# background image with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have already plot the points on the image of PUBG map, like this:

[image]

However, the bottom edge of the image is below `0,` and the top edge is over `8e+05`, same as left edge and right edge.

How do I fix the code to adjust the image to width: `0` to `8e+05`, and height: `0 to 8e+05`?

```
miramar <- readJPEG("/Users/lucyzhang/Waterloo/stat 847/project/pubg/miramar.jpg")

deaths1 <- read.csv(header=T,"/Users/lucyzhang/Waterloo/stat 847/project/pubg/deaths/kill_match_stats_final_0.csv",sep=',',stringsAsFactors=F)

victims1 <- deaths1[,c("victim_position_x","victim_position_y")]

victims1 <- subset(victims1,victim_position_x>0,victim_position_y>0)

s_victims1 <- victims1[sample(nrow(victims1),10000),]
ggplot(s_victims1, aes(x=s_victims1$victim_position_x, y=s_victims1$victim_position_y)) +
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(miramar, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")),xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
  geom_point(colour="red", alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Try `+ scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` (and same for `y`).

Comment: I suggest `+ coord_fixed(expand = FALSE)`.

Comment: @r2evans It works, thank you

Comment: @Axeman Yes, this works better, returns the original picture. Thank you

Comment: I agree that `coord_fixed` is more concise. In my mind, I had projected this type of data and image as a project of lat/lon, in which case the default `ratio=1` argument would not work ... but it's not lat/lon, so you're good.